# Android Studio - Gradle commands spanning multiple Java process

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

When I run `gradlew` commands or when Android Studio starts, It spanning one java process in every second, Which ends up using 100% of system memory usage. It was fine in the last android studio version, any idea how to fix this?

**About the system**

```
Android Studio 4.1.2
java version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing) 
Gradle 6.5

CPU AMD Ryzen 7 2700
Memory 32GB
```

I tried updating `gradle.properties`

- `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`
- `org.gradle.jvmargs = -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is Windows 10 Mobile hotspot, When the Mobile hotspot is turned on Windows refuses to connect `127.0.0.1`, Which is necessary for the Gradle daemon.

The fix is just to turn off the **Windows Mobile Hotspot**